# Overview of robust/regularized portfolio selection

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-selection, portfolio-optimization, robust-optimization

I am looking for either a **review paper** or individual papers on **portfolio selection** using **robust statistics or regularization** (e.g. LASSO, Ridge, etc.)

I.e. a review on methods along the lines of:

M Carrasco, N Noumon, Optimal portfolio selection using regularization, 2011
http://www.admissions.american.edu/cas/economics/info-metrics/pdf/upload/Carrasco-Nov-2011-submission.pdf

D Goldfarb, G Iyengar, Robust portfolio selection problems, 2003
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.100.7182&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lyxor white paper [Regularization of Portfolio Allocation](http://www.lyxor.com/publications/white-papers/wp/82/) contains a lot on this topic. The head of quant research there, Thierry Roncalli, also held a [talk](http://www.thierry-roncalli.com/download/big-data-in-asset-management.pdf) about this recently.

Comment: That stuff about non-negative matrix factorization is interesting. Thanks for that.

Comment: @John I thought that too. Basic concept but nice interpretation. Roncalli often presents such 'big picture'things.